# How to get Datacontext of Child control WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datacontext

In App.xaml

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:CurrentSheetVM}">
                    <vw:CurrentSheetV/>
                </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ParentVM}">
                    <vw:ParentControlV/>
                </DataTemplate>
```

In XAML:

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" > 
                <ContentControl Name="childCtrl1" Content="{Binding CurrentSheet1}"/>
                <ContentControl Name="childCtrl2" Content="{Binding CurrentSheet2}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

In ParentVM:

```
private ViewModelBase currentSheet1;
       public ViewModelBase CurrentSheet1
       {
           get { return currentSheet1; }
           set { currentSheet = value;
           this.OnPropertyChanged("CurrentSheet1");
           }
       }

public ParentVM()
{
CurrentSheet1= new CurrentSheetVM(some param1);
CurrentSheet2= new CurrentSheetVM(some param2);
}
```

in code behind

```
Object dc_Child1= childCtrl1.DataContext;
Object dc_Child2= childCtrl2.DataContext;
```

Here am trying to get the datacontext of both child controls,but its showing parents DataContext in dc_Child1 and dc_Child2.
Is there a way to get the datacontexts of these two?

Comment: I'm confused about what you're trying to retrieve, the datacontext of these two "is" the same as their parent as it's not set, you're binding one of their properties but you're not binding their datacontext so it's inherited, or am i missunderstanding your question?

Comment: I have updated the question, actually Parent control has its own datacontext

Comment: @DarkKnight: it isn't clear, where do you intialize data contexts of child controls. Binding `Content` to something isn't the same as setting `DataContext`.

Comment: @Dennis: I have CurrentSheet1 as Property in parents viewmodel

 private ViewModelBase currentSheet1;
       public ViewModelBase CurrentSheet1
       {
           get { return currentSheet1; }
           set { currentSheet = value;
           this.OnPropertyChanged("CurrentSheet1");
           }
       }

Comment: @Dark Knight please check that these ContentControls are able to use the DataTemplate correctly. I.e. you have defined that DataTemplate correctly. either in the ResourceDictionary or in this page.

Comment: @Alok:Yes, Binding n all working properly and loading perfectly.But my question is there any way I can know what are the DataContexts of each child control which have their own DC's

Comment: Oh wait!, comment from @Dennis making sense to me now. I was under the impression that binding and DataContext are same. I need to look at the difference b/w them now

Comment: @Alok: you're pointing OP to learn about `DataContext`, but you're misunderstanding this concept yourself. That's the irony, I think. Binding works in context of... `DataContext`. That's why it is a *context* - it "attaches" some data source to the framework element and tells binding engine: "hey, man, if I mean {Binding}, then consider that thing as a data source".

Comment: @Dennis I was just pointing out some points as the question was not clear. And I think you have misunderstood the original problem here. it's not a problem of DataContext initialization as your comment suggest. above all we can't declare the DataContext for ContentControl explicitly that will nullify the content binding.( hopefully you are getting the class hierarchy design here which is implicit.). you are just generalising the problem by talking about how datacontext and binding works. even though dark knight didn't even know the difference between the two that wasn't his problem.

Comment: @Dennis to understand the situation here completely please download the project from the link. and you might learn some new things about datacontext/DataTemplate. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31837/Creating-an-Internationalized-Wizard-in-WPF

Comment: @Dennis N you didn't answer my question? what is not true in my answer? would appreciate if you point out that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that setting `ContentControl.Content` is not the same, as setting `ContentControl.DataContext`.

Consider this code. Here are view models:

```
public class ParentViewModel
{
    public ChildViewModel_A Child_A { get; } = new ChildViewModel_A
    {
        IntProperty = 100
    };

    public ChildViewModel_B Child_B { get; } = new ChildViewModel_B
    {
        StringProperty = "Hello, world!"
    };
}

public class ChildViewModel_A
{
    public int IntProperty { get; set; }
}

public class ChildViewModel_B
{
    public string StringProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Here is markup:

```
<Window x:Class="DataContextsDemo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataContextsDemo">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ParentViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ChildViewModel_A}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding IntProperty}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ChildViewModel_B}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringProperty}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </StackPanel.Resources>

        <ContentControl x:Name="Child_A_View" Content="{Binding Child_A}"/>
        <ContentControl x:Name="Child_B_View" Content="{Binding Child_B}"/>
        <Button Content="Click me!" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

By default both `ContentControl`s "inherit" `DataContext` from their parent (in this particular case, from grand-parent, `Window`).

If you will click the button, this code in code behind:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(Child_A_View.DataContext == Child_B_View.DataContext);
}
```

will write `True` into output window, because data context of both controls is instance of `ParentViewModel`.

But if XAML will be modified a little like this:

```
    <ContentControl x:Name="Child_A_View" DataContext="{Binding Child_A}" Content="{Binding}"/>
    <ContentControl x:Name="Child_B_View" DataContext="{Binding Child_B}" Content="{Binding}"/>
```

`Debug.WriteLine` will write `False`, because this sets `DataContext` explicitly and breaks default "inheritance" strategy. Note, that this expression:

```
DataContext="{Binding Child_A}"
```

still works with parent `DataContext`, while this one:

```
Content="{Binding}"
```

works with new data context, which is assigned by previous expression.

Also note, that *content* of content controls in this sample will remain the same. The only thing, that changes is a data context.

Comment: :Thanks, This clears my confusion b/w DataContext and Binding.